# Why does Indian mythology not have humongous beasts like that of Chinese dragon?

Tags: mythical-creatures, chinese, india

This is a question out of curiosity. I noticed that Indian culture and Chinese culture very near by proximity, but there has been no sign of any dragon in the Indian culture.

Answer (score 8):

Even though the geographical locations might be very near, it has to be noticed that there hasn't been a considerable mixture of both the cultures due to the following reasons:

- The Himalayas acted as a very big barrier between the geographical locations of India and China, which made it very difficult for the cultures to mix.
- The China mainland and India were ruled by rulers from completely different cultures, namely the Mughals in the North, the Cholas and Pallavas in the South, whose cultures are very different from each other.
- However, it is interesting to notice that the reptile `snake`(called as **Naag**) is also an important part of Indian folklore, which has been associated with Gods like Siva and Vishnu. However, there hasn't been any significant records of a flying reptile in Indian folklore.

But, claiming of no `humungous beasts` in Indian folklore is wrong. India did had beasts like Airavat, Hanuma, Garuda, etc.